# Large Message Handling in Durable Functions

Tags: azure-durable-functions

Hey Durable Functions people, I've just hit my first instance of having a large message url returned in the output property of a status query response. E.g.

```
http:\\xx.xx.xx.xx\devstoreaccount1\durablefunctionshub-largemessages\a2f52688638149d69dec9e49d0a6ce35/history-00000000000000ca-executioncompleted-result.json.gz
```

Is there a pattern / recommended library for downloading and deserializing these?

EDIT: I realize that there’s the GZipStream class but I’m wondering if there’s a new/little known method within the functions framework to take care of it for me?